# Implementing a ViewController for Android for a shared application.

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, auth0

Im trying to do this for a shared application in Xamarin. In the iOS section is looks like:

```
var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
var vc = window.RootViewController;
var user = await auth0.LoginAsync(vc, withRefreshToken: true);
```

but for android I have no idea how to implement the view controller 'vc' to pass to LoginAsync().

Comment: `Android.App.Application.Context` : https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.App.Application.Context/

Answer (score 0):

You can always refer to https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/xamarin. In Android referring `this` will give the current context you are in. `this` context is very much similar to `window.RootViewController` for iOS. So all you need to do is calling

```
var user = auth0.LoginAsync(this, withRefreshToken: true);
```

If you want to show the login in other window for android, get the context and assign it to a `Android.App.Application.Context` type variable and replace `this` with the variable in the previously mentioned code.